For pytest, how to generate and load a dict for every module
I need a way to generate a dictionary containing unique paths for every pytest module/file in a given directory. It needs to be accessible before any test is even run to define the paths for the file:
TEST_DIRS = {}

path1 = TEST_DIRS['path']
path2 = TEST_DIRS['input']

def test_something():
    target = path1 / 'input_file'
    ....
def test_another_thing():
    ....

Also there should be directory config file like conftest to perform the generating actions required by each module. Generator would create directories based on the test name.
I tried using conftest.py file and pytest_collection_modify_items but it still makes the TEST_DIRS work only inside test function not before them.
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    for item in items:
        module_name = item.module.__name__
        test_paths = {
            key: value.format(test_name=module_name, timestamp=timestamp)
            for key, value in BASE_TEST_DIRS.items()
        }
        test_paths = {
            key: home / Path(value)
            for key, value in test_paths.items()
        }
    
        for key, path in test_paths.items():
            if key.startswith('output'):
                if not os.path.exists(path):
                    os.makedirs(path)

        item.module.TEST_DIRS = test_paths
   


Do you need to use an Initialization Hook such as pytest_configure? https://pytest-with-eric.com/hooks/pytest-configure/

You can use pytest_configure and pytest_collection_modifyitems(Writing hook functions - pytest documentation).
pytest_configure: You can set up the TEST_DIRS structure early in the pytest lifecycle, before the test functions are executed.
pytest_collection_modifyitems: You can create the directories dynamically based on the test module or name during test collection.
Define Global TEST_DIRS: You can use a conftest.py file to manage the paths and make them accessible to all test modules.
Below is the code template which you can refer for implementation:
import os
import pytest
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

TEST_DIRS = {}

BASE_TEST_DIRS = {
    'input': 'test_data/{test_name}/input_{timestamp}',
    'output': 'test_data/{test_name}/output_{timestamp}'
}

def pytest_configure(config):
    global TEST_DIRS
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
    TEST_DIRS['base'] = Path.home() / 'test_data'
    TEST_DIRS['timestamp'] = timestamp

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    global TEST_DIRS

    for item in items:
        module_name = item.module.__name__

        test_paths = {
            key: value.format(test_name=module_name, timestamp=TEST_DIRS['timestamp'])
            for key, value in BASE_TEST_DIRS.items()
        }

        test_paths = {key: Path.home() / Path(value) for key, value in test_paths.items()}

        for key, path in test_paths.items():
            if not os.path.exists(path):
                os.makedirs(path)

        item.module.TEST_DIRS = test_paths
        print(f"Created paths for module {module_name}: {test_paths}"


Explanation of above code
Role of pytest_configure:This is a hook which is executed before any tests are collected or executed. It sets up a timestamp and initialises a base directory (TEST_DIRS) that will be shared across test modules.
Role of pytest_collection_modifyitems:This is another hook that is invoked after test collection, but before the tests are executed. For each test module, it dynamically generates paths (based on the module name) for input/output directories and creates them on the filesystem.
The TEST_DIRS dictionary is assigned to each test module via item.module. So that each test can access it.
